# Order relation on the geometric line as defined in Kock's synthetic differential geometry

Tags: category-theory, real-numbers, order-theory, constructive-mathematics, synthetic-differential-geometry

I'm trying to figure out to what an order relation $<$ would look like on the geometric line $R$ as defined in Kock's synthetic differential geometry.

If I understand correctly (in constructive analysis) $\mathbb{R}$ admits a linear order $<$.

**Question**: What would be the preferred way (if any) to define an order on $R$?

For example, if $d \in R$ satisfies the equation $d^2 = 0$, up to one of the following can be true, lest $d = 0$ be the only solution of the equation:

1. $d \not< 0$ and $0 \not< d$
2. $<$ is a [connected irreflexive comparison](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/irreflexive+comparison), more specifically, if $x \not< y$ and $y \not< x$, then $x = y$.

I'm inclined to think 1. is true, and that $<$ defined on $R$ would be an irreflexive comparison satisfying asymmetry (i.e. $x < y \implies y \not< x$, which implies irreflexivity). I think then the preorder $ \le $ defined as the opposite of $\not<$ would end up being a total preorder, for which $d^2 = 0$ implies $d \le 0$ and $0 \le d$ (but not $d = 0$). However I haven't yet found such a relation being defined on any writing.

Comment: Why can't both (1) and (2) be true?

Comment: Being connected (2) means that if x<y is false and y<x is false, then x=y. So if (1) is true then d = 0, and we don't what this in R (the geometric line, not the real numbers) because we want the set of solutions of d^2 = 0 to be larger than {0}.

Comment: Ah, I just clicked on the link and did not notice the separate issue of being connected. The general way this is resolved is simply not assuming that the relation is connected. $<$ is a transitive irreflexive comparison, but it is not assumed to be connected.

Comment: @MarkSaving Edited (2) to make it more clear.

Comment: One way to define $<$ is as follows: First, define $a \leq b$ to be $\exists c (c^2 + a = b)$. Let $i : \mathbb{Q} \to R$ be the canonical inclusion map: then define $a < b$ to be $\exists q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q} (a \leq i(q_1) \land q_1 < q_2 \land i(q_2) \leq b)$. Obviously, under this definition all $d^2 = 0$ infinitesimals satisfy $d \leq 0 \leq d$. You'd need an axiom declaring that $\leq$ is transitive which essentially means that square roots exist.